# upload a file to s3 using Laravel, but using metadata login

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am using laravel to upload a file to s3 bucket.
on config->filesystems we have following details for s3.

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => env('FILE_DRIVER'),
        'region' => env('S3_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

on .env file we have following values

```
FILE_DRIVER=s3
S3_REGION=bucket region
S3_BUCKET=Bucket name
```

note that we are not using any

```
'key'    => 'your-key',
'secret' => 'your-secret',
```

we just try to use the AWS metadata login in order to authenticate user and upload the file.

My problem is, how to use the existing file upload feature on Laravel in this case? 
If the environment is Local or s3, is there a way that we can use the same code to upload the image.
Can anyone guide me how to do it? i am clueless here....

if more information needed, let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel Storage class as following.
You can call methods on s3 using $s3 object.

```
use Storage;

$s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
```

Comment: Will this help me to connect to the S3, without passing key and secret code?. we have only driver, region and bucket name